# Couldn't get VMCI driver version Error VMWare WorkStation

Tags: windows, windows-10, vmware, vmware-workstation

While installing Windows 10 on my VMWare Workstation Pro 15, I kept getting this error

[image]

Any hint on how should I fix it ?

Comment: Do you have hardware virtualization and VT-x enable in the HOST BIOS?  Close down, restart in BIOS to check.

Comment: did you try reinstalling?  Ideally, uninstall, reboot, and reinstall.

Comment: See: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/596235